# c++ only letters and empty space input validation

Tags: c++, validation, input

My target is to validate c++ input that it will hold only small and capital letters and empty space. Can I do that without for loop? My current code is:

```
 bool validateInput()
            char c;
            string result;
            cin >> result;

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                c = result.at(i);
                if ( !( ( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ) || ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) || c == ' ' ) )
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: " Can I do that without for loop?" Investigate std::string::find_first_of.

Comment: The problem is that there needs to be some kind of loop to check all the characters in a string.  Whether you use your loop or a loop in a function like `std::string::find`, there still needs to be a loop.

Comment: Read about `std::isalpha`. There is nothing in C or C++ that guarantees that that test will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without a for loop, although you'll obviously still need to use a loop, I guess the modern C++ way would be to use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) , ( you can also use [`std::none_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) as pointed out by @NathanOliver which wraps `std::find_if` and returns a boolean instead of an iterator ). It's also probably a good idea to use [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha), partly because a character set might not have alphabetical characters mapped to decimal values in order, and partly because it is easier to write :-)

```
bool validateInput()
{
    std::string result;
    std::cin >> result;
    return std::none_of(result.begin(), result.end(), [](const char& c)
    {
        return !(std::isalpha(c) || c == ' '); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) returns a bool so that might be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thanks for answer, my question was am I able to do it without loop. One side question please. Can I add number to that condition? Is there any isnumber method?

Comment: @TeodorKolev "Is there any isnumber method?" , yup, I think [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) is the most appropriate here.